# Python: How to implement a new line in every row of a nested list

Tags: python

So, recently I have been trying to create a random nested list generator to further my python knowledge. I have encountered a few problems that tested me. I have overcome all of them except for my current one. I want to make a new line for every row, so it is easier to visualize. I have looked at other posts on this website and tried to implement one of the solutions to one of them; however it only returned the error -

```
 TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
```

My code is the following -

```py
import random

def random_2d_array(rows, columns):

    output = []
    iteration = 0
    while iteration != rows:
        i2 = 0
        iteration += 1
        output.append([])
        output = '\n'.join(output)
        while i2 != columns:
            i2 += 1
            num = random.randint(1, 10)
            col = list(output[iteration - 1])
            col.insert(i2 - 1, num)
    return output


print(random_2d_array(3, 3))
```

Comment: If it's not numpy, then don't call it an array, but a nested list.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the information.

Comment: move the print inside the function per row and then just call the function. don't return anything.

Comment: Nathan, can you type the code to clarify on what you mean?

Comment: call the function like this
random_2d_array(3,3)
inside the function you will print for each row

Comment: Ok, I will test that and report back whether or not it worked

Comment: Alright, I'm a bit confused as to where I put the print. I know that it should be inside the function, but where precisely?

Comment: @Xandrios check the solution below to print the each list in a nested list in a new line

Comment: @sambasiva rao I have and it worked like a charm, thank you! :D

Comment: @sambasivarao Now the only thing I need is for you to please explain to me how it works

Comment: @Xandrios see the edit below. :D

Comment: @sambasivarao Thank you so much bro! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following hack inside the function

```
return '\n'.join([str(i) for i in output])
```

**Edit**:

This takes each list in a nested list and converts it to a string and join the converted list to the end of the newline character and returns the result